# Excel formula with 3 variables for VAT & Savings, stuck on 3rd variable

Tags: excel, variables, formula

I'm looking into making an excel sheet for keeping track of my owed VAT & savings, it goes as followed:

I have 3 sources of income
- Income with VAT
- income without VAT
- Unsuspected income

for each income I need a different outcome

- With VAT[enter image description here][1]
  Excel has to take the Total amount, take 21% off, and show this in a separate column, then, of the total - 21% I want it to take 10% and put it in the savings column
- withouth VAT
  just take the total and take 10 off and put it in the savings column 
  (This is all working, I did it with a single IF formula (see print screen)

but then for the third (unsuspected income) I want to take the total, and place 50% directly in the savings column, however, I can't seem to put this in the formula.

thanks in advance! example is below

printscreen : https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6WtE.png

Comment: Please show what you have tried and where you have run into problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got what you mean. Why wouldn't adding something like

```
(D17>0; D17/2)
```

to your IFS function solve your problem?

In any case, it seems that you lack a criteria to your "income without VAT" test. Perhaps this explain why adding another variable wouldn't work.

You have a first if for column B, then add X amount to savings, but you don't have a similar semantics to column C (just a value, not a test). Eventually, excel is interpreting this as an "else", rather than another IF test.

Just to illustrate what I mean, it seems that you have

```
IFS(B14>0; (B14-E14)/10; C14/10)
```

So as to say "IF B14, savings 1, otherwise savings 2".

But perhaps what you really want is something like

```
IFS(B14>0; (B14-E14)/10; C14>0; C14/10; D14>0; D14/2)
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy... I feel sorry for wasting your time! that's what I needed! Thanks you!

Comment: Don't bother saying sorry for anyone here for asking genuine questions, we are all in the same boat!